# .NET vs Java for web application development in a startup company

Tags: java, .net, grails, playframework, web-frameworks

We are startup in web application domain. We currently have two applications built for two different industry. Both of them were developed from scratch in `yii`, a PHP framework.
We are now planning on selling it as a product and will even think about hosting it as a SAAS later.

So we are thinking of moving the applications to either Java or .NET. But are stuck at which to choose. So instead of comparing them, i will list down our requirements.

1. RAD Development
2. Would prefer MVC ( Since we already have experience with Yii)
3. Good web controls ( Better if there is *easy* integration from the framework itself with  Dojo/EXTJS/ Other JS library.
4. Component driven development ( Eg. We should be able to plug our "HR Module" to both our app easily)
5. Ability to make a component-like library in that technology, so tomorrow if we have to develop another such web-app for another industry, we should be able to do it FAST!!

What we have considered so far:

1. .NET MVC 3.0 ( can we use webform controls with MVC? )
2. Grails
3. Play!

Our final aim is to build expertise in any one of the technology, so we would be able to roll out applications/features faster. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Note:

- .NET licensing is not an issue.
- PHP is not an option because of lack of skilled PHP developers where we operate.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without a flame war ensuing.

Comment: Our Skillset: C++, PHP (Yii Framework)

Comment: Are you sure that switching to a new, unknown technology is a good thing?

Comment: Its a good thing to be done now. Rather than 3-5 yrs down the line!

Comment: As long as you have actually considered the question, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend ASP.NET, but that's my area of expertise, so I'm going to be pretty biased...

As far as your MVC3 question - yes, you can mix and match MVC with traditional asp.net web forms. You can create .aspx pages do all the web forms stuff even though you're in a MVC project. MVC also has top-notch integration with the jQuery javascript library, even with documentation, so you get code-completion when writing jQuery in Visual Studio, which is pretty handy if you're going to be doing a lot of javascript development.

Answer (score 0):

The two platforms are enough alike that it usually is something else that decides what to do.

I would recommend that you have a look at this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20255/what-would-you-choose-for-your-project-between-net-and-java-at-this-point-in-tim

This question also [has an answer from me](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20255/what-would-you-choose-for-your-project-between-net-and-java-at-this-point-in-tim/20257#20257), listing some of my concerns.

Answer (score 0):

As a .NET developer I would recommend you to... stay with PHP. Do you want to rewrite the whole application only because of lack of enough skilled PHP programmers? Really? There are less radical options: learn your developers, hire developers from other locations, etc.

Comment: Valid point. But we cant use PHP because of some other reasons also. Thats why i kept it out of the comparison. Regarding rewriting, its just a minor goal, what we want is to establish a strong expertise in one of the technology to ease in development in further projects